# sublime text / textmate color scheme - change highlight color

Tags: themes, sublimetext, textmate, color-scheme

i want some of the highlighting color of sublime text themes to be more intense.

1) when i select a word, sublime text marks all instances of this word in the file. it marks it with very light square around the word. i want to know how to change color, make it more intense and if i can color the inside of the square.

2) when the text sign is on one side of brackets / parenthesis, it marks both sides with very light underline. same thing - i want to know if and how i can control the color and intensity of this underline, and if i can also color above the underline (the entire character background).

I add 2 pictures of exactly what i mean, when i use the "Neon" color scheme:
https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme

[image: instances]
[image: brackets]

what fields should i change?
could not figure out myself.

thank you.

Comment: Try using the [scopehunter package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeHunter). It will show you what the definition is for a selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the Neon theme - thank you for using it! Unfortunately, the two examples you show, automatic highlighting of matching selections and bracket matching, don't appear to be separately themeable. If you take a look at the source of [`Neon.tmTheme`](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/blob/master/Neon.tmTheme#L20-L47) lines 20-47, you'll see the keys that set various colors for everything *except* the syntax highlighting - the selection color and outline, caret color, indentation guides, etc. I've collected all these values over a couple years of looking at lots of different color schemes and a lot of googling, but I haven't found any settings that specifically target what you're asking about. Instead, it appears that they are colored with either the `caret` color or, more likely, the `foreground` color (they are both the same in Neon).

So, while unfortunately there isn't much you can do about the first issue, there is a solution for bracket matching - the [`BracketHighlighter`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter) plugin.

[image: Neon with BracketHighlighter]

Neon includes [settings](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/blob/master/Neon.tmTheme#L2556-L2680) for BracketHighlighter, so all you need to do is configure the plugin itself to use them. Here are the `"bracket_styles"` I use:

```js
"bracket_styles": {
    // "default" and "unmatched" styles are special
    // styles. If they are not defined here,
    // they will be generated internally with
    // internal defaults.

    // "default" style defines attributes that
    // will be used for any style that does not
    // explicitly define that attribute.  So if
    // a style does not define a color, it will
    // use the color from the "default" style.
    "default": {
        "icon": "dot",
        // BH1's original default color for reference
        // "color": "entity.name.class",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.default",
        "style": "underline"
    },

    // This particular style is used to highlight
    // unmatched bracekt pairs.  It is a special
    // style.
    "unmatched": {
        "icon": "question",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.unmatched",
        "style": "outline"
    },
    // User defined region styles
    "curly": {
        "icon": "curly_bracket",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.curly",
        "style": "underline"
    },
    "round": {
        "icon": "round_bracket",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.round",
        "style": "underline"
    },
    "square": {
        "icon": "square_bracket",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.square",
        "style": "underline"
    },
    "angle": {
        "icon": "angle_bracket",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.angle",
        "style": "underline"
    },
    "tag": {
        "icon": "tag",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.tag",
        "style": "outline"
    },
    "single_quote": {
        "icon": "single_quote",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.quote",
        "style": "underline"
    },
    "double_quote": {
        "icon": "double_quote",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.quote",
        "style": "underline"
    },
    "regex": {
        "icon": "regex",
        "color": "brackethighlighter.quote",
        "style": "underline"
    }
},
```

Hopefully this helps you out. If you have any other questions, concerns, or general feedback about Neon, please feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/issues) and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much. Could not imagine I'll receive such a full and detailed answer :). And thank you for writing the theme.